# How can i plot the decision boundary for a multilabel SVM problem using caret in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, svm, r-caret

I've built an SVM model using R's caret package:

```
set.seed(1234567)


SVM_caret <- train(x = x_train, y = y_train$label, 
               method = "svmLinear", tuneGrid = expand.grid(
              C = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1)),
              metric = "ROC",
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, classProbs = T),
              maxit = 100)
```

I tried to implement [this](https://michael.hahsler.net/SMU/EMIS7332/R/viz_classifier.html) code to plot the decision bounday of my model, but i'm getting several errors. This is the model's confusion matrix:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction class_1 class_2 class_3 class_4
   class_1       9       0       0       0
   class_2       0       7       0       0
   class_3       3       0       6       0
   class_4       0       0       0       7

Overall Statistics

               Accuracy : 0.9062          
                 95% CI : (0.7498, 0.9802)
    No Information Rate : 0.375           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 5.706e-10       

                  Kappa : 0.8743          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              

Statistics by Class:

                     Class: class_1 Class: class_2 Class: class_3 Class: class_4
Sensitivity                  0.7500         1.0000         1.0000         1.0000
Specificity                  1.0000         1.0000         0.8846         1.0000
Pos Pred Value               1.0000         1.0000         0.6667         1.0000
Neg Pred Value               0.8696         1.0000         1.0000         1.0000
Prevalence                   0.3750         0.2188         0.1875         0.2188
Detection Rate               0.2812         0.2188         0.1875         0.2188
Detection Prevalence         0.2812         0.2188         0.2812         0.2188
Balanced Accuracy            0.8750         1.0000         0.9423         1.0000
```

There are 4 classes to predict, i don't know if is it really possible to get this plot built, but i couldn't figure out how to get it done. Is there any function or way to visualize this decission boundary??

Since i can't just copy paste my data here, i'll add a link to it on google drive, so you can download and reproduce the problem, don't worry for the size as it is really lightweight.

Here are the links:

[train_data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XRLCmkKuhqAIdLtgwJMsI3XRLeeBKXHQ)

[train_labels](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OreTcKGOBoPJcViVNqWR5QR-Ih6xNStq)

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: This function only allows two predictors which is the maximum number of dimensions you can represent in a standard plot. If you have more predictors you cannot visualize the decision boundary. If you want to visualize it you may have to use a decision tree.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen, than you for your answer. is  there no way to represent the classes using different colors or something and just draw the boundary lines around?

Comment: I don't think it works. What would be your axes? Every point in your dataset lies in a 10 dimensional space. So you'd have to display 10 decision boundaries, that's not possible in a plot.

Comment: allright @Humpelstielzchen, that sounds good enough as an answer. Let's give it some time to see if someone wants to make a contribution to this question, and if nothing happens, i'll be glad if you post your answer so i can accept it. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

You can only visualize decision boundaries in two dimensional plot when you have two predictors. You are using 10 predictors however, which means every point exists in a 10-dimensional space this can't be plotted the way you intend to.

Choosing a subset of predictors to plot would give you the ability to plot decision boundaries but they won't divide the data in your plot in any meaningful way.

If you definitly want to visualize a set of decision rules you can do a decision tree.

```
dtree <- train(x = svm_data[,-1], y = svm_labels$label, 
                   method = "rpart",
                   metric = "Accuracy",
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3, classProbs = T),
                   cp = 0.005,
                   maxdepth = 3)



plot(dtree$finalModel, margin = 0.2)
text(dtree$finalModel)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Humpelstielzchen, thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know that we could use decission trees this way to get some sort of decision rules represented. I'll have a look at it. Thank you very much again :)